# find command: delete everything but one folder

Tags: linux, bash, find, rm

I have this command:

```
find ~/Desktop/testrm -mindepth 1 -path ~/Desktop/testrm/.snapshot -o -mtime +2 -prune -exec rm -rf {} +
```

I want it to work as is, but it must avoid to remove a specific directory ($ROOT_DIR/$DATA_DIR).

- it must remove the files inside the directory but not the directory itself
- the flag "r" in rm is needed because it has to delete other directories
- -prune is not suitable since it will discard the content and also sub directories

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude individual paths using the short circuiting behavior of `-o` (like you already did with `~/Desktop/testrm/.snapshot`).
However, for each excluded path you also have to exclude all of its parent directories. Otherwise you would delete `a/b/c` by deleting `a/b/` or `a/` with `rm -rf`.

In the following script, the function `orParents` generates a part of the `find` command. Example:
`find $(orParents a/b/c) ...` would run
`find -path a/b/c -o -path a/b -o -path a -o ...`.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
orParents() {
  p="$1"
  while
    printf -- '-path %q -o' "$p"
    p=$(dirname "$p")
    [ "$p" != . ]
  do :; done
}
find ~/Desktop/testrm -mindepth 1 \
  $(orParents "$ROOT_DIR/$DATA_DIR") -path ~/Desktop/testrm/.snapshot -o \
  -mtime +2 -prune -exec rm -rf {} +
```

**Warning:** You have to make sure that `$ROOT_DIR/$DATA_DIR` does *not* end with a `/` and does *not* contain glob characters like `*`, `?`, and `[]`.
<sub>Spaces are ok as `printf %q` escapes them correctly. However, `find -path` interprets its argument as a glob pattern independently. We could do a double quoting mechanism. Maybe something like `printf %q "$(sed 's/[][*?\]/\\&/' <<< "$p")"`, but I'm not so sure about how exactly `find -path` interprets its argument.</sub>

Alternatively, you could write a script `isParentOf` and do ...

```
find ... -exec isParentOf "$ROOT_DIR/$DATA_DIR" {} \; -o ...
```

... to exclude `$ROOT_DIR/$DATA_DIR` and all of its parents. This is probably safer and more portable, but slower and a hassle to set up (`find -exec bash -c ...` and so on) if you don't want to add a script file to your path.